# Can't get set-cookie from header in response with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, http, cookies, httpresponse, setcookie

I have tried 3 differents http library in node

1. node request
2. node requestify
3. node needle

All of the 3 libraries can't get my set-cookie from my response

Request

```
15:32:52 - WARN  - now testing with request
{ 'x-powered-by': 'Express',
  'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  'content-length': '4591',
  date: 'Thu, 11 Dec 2014 14:32:52 GMT',
  connection: 'keep-alive' }
```

Needle

```
15:32:52 - WARN  - now testing with needle
{ 'x-powered-by': 'Express',
  'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  'content-length': '4591',
  date: 'Thu, 11 Dec 2014 14:32:52 GMT',
  connection: 'close' }
```

Requestify

```
15:32:52 - WARN  - now testing with requestify
{ 'x-powered-by': 'Express',
  'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  'content-length': '4591',
  date: 'Thu, 11 Dec 2014 14:32:52 GMT',
  connection: 'keep-alive' }
```

Here's the result header with a wget

```
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  X-Powered-By: Express
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Date: Thu, 11 Dec 2014 14:38:49 GMT
  Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
  Last-Modified: Thu, 11 Dec 2014 09:56:58 GMT
  ETag: W/"7c2-2140188116"
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Content-Length: 1986
  set-cookie: session=s%3AHI2alIkPOxVLXgJCymvAPbTZt1urIpEE.dBB7ZrpWjKAkwSALBVgbyJtRq9ZABMq9VJh%2F3XT6r8A; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 11 Dec 2014 15:08:49 GMT; HttpOnly
  Connection: keep-alive
Length: 1986 (1.9K) [text/html]
```

If this can help, here are my headers from my request

```
var commonHeaders = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'User-Agent': 'request'
};
```

While firefox, chrome, and wget can get the full header, I am not able to do authentification with node.
Is it a probleme with Node ? Should I do that in Python ?

Edit :

I have tried to remove the data posted through node, I also have the same response than with wget.
While I am using a browser and go through the login action, it return my json + set-cookie.

Why isn't that possible with node ?

Comment: I think you are requesting two different URLs/requests. wget is seeing `text/html` and other headers, whereas the node requests are seeing `application/json` and fewer headers.

Comment: yes this is right, if I remove the data posted in my request, I also received a setCookie from node. But it is statusCode 401 and user or redirected to login. The thing is, it should return a set-cookie, I can see it if I use the login action from a browser

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't use the cookies correctly. Usually they are not accessed directly as header variables. See [request](https://github.com/request/request) documentation for how to handle cookies, there are good examples there.

> Cookies are disabled by default (else, they would be used in
>   subsequent requests). To enable cookies, set jar to true (either in
>   defaults or options) and install tough-cookie.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have tried with jar and tough-cookie. Still doesn't have a set-cookie, in my response. You say they are good example there, I don't think they are.

Comment: I have done a jsfiddle for your suggestion, tried a few combinaison and none work, still unauthorized. http://jsfiddle.net/u8x3oxb1/

Comment: Well, it's not a node problem.The problem is somewhere in authentication. The unauthorized is on loginScript or on data request. What lib do you use for authentication?

Comment: express-session. It's fun because if I succeed my auth, I have no cookies, otherwise, I got one but I don't need it. :/

Comment: Can you post a the part of code that is responsible for authorization and the part that is responsible for login? It is hard to tell otherwise.